# I am trying to use this code based on mtcnn for face detection it is correct but it wont work

Tags: deep-learning, face-detection

1. this code uses mtcnn for face detection from a frame
2. it usses opencv to draw boxes on detected faces

   ````
    import cv2 
    from facenet_pytorch import MTCNN
    import numpy as np
    class FaceDetector(object):
        def __init__(self,mtcnn):
            self.mtcnn=mtcnn
        ```
   ````

   .It seems that it is not getting inside the _draw()

   ```
           def _draw(self,frame,boxes,probs,landmarks):
               for box, prob,ld in zip(boxes,probs,landmarks):
                   #rectangle
                   print("in draw")
   ```

   the opencv rectanle drawer

   ```
                   cv2.rectangle(frame,(box[0],box[1]),(box[2],box[3]),(0,0,255),thickness=2)

               return frame
   ```

   ````
        ```
   ````

   run() to run the app

   ````
           def run(self):
               cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
               while True :
                   ret,frame= cap.read()

                   try :
                       boxes, probs,landamarks=self.mtcnn.detect(frame,landmarks=True)

                       self._draw(frame,boxes,probs,landmarks)

                   except :
                       pass
                   cv2.imshow("face detector",frame)
                   ``` 
   to stop the execution
   ````

   ```
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFf==ord('q'):
                    break
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
   ```

   ```
   main app
   here we instanciate MTCNN and try to run it on our frame
   ```

   ```
    mtcnn= MTCNN(keep_all=True)
    fcd=FaceDetector(mtcnn)
    fcd.run()
   ```